# Creating a binned lead and lag in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a type of lead and lag. The `dplyr::lead` and `dplyr::lag` function almost get what I want, but it's missing a crucial step where it "fills" in the values I want. Take the following example:

```
treatment <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)

df_treatment <- tibble(treatment)

df_treatment
```

I want a lead and lag column of the treatment column, but I want it to have 3 leading 1s for each treatment indicator. The `dplyr::lead` function can give me only 1 lead since it can't take a vector in it's `n` argument.

This is my desired output:

```
lead_2 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
lead_1 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)

df_desired <- tibble(lead_2, lead_1, treatment)
df_desired
```

The purpose of this is to create 6 leads and lags columns similar to the `df_desired`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `treatment` is like that, define new function `leead` that can put vector instead of `n`.

```
leead <- function(x, v){
  xx <- rep(0, length(x))
  for(i in v){
    xx <- xx + lead(x, i)
  }
  xx[is.na(xx)] <- 0
  xx
}

tibble(treatment) %>%
  mutate(lead_1 = leead(treatment, c(1:3)),
         lead_2 = leead(treatment, c(4:6))) 

   treatment lead_1 lead_2
       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1         0      0      1
 2         0      0      1
 3         0      0      1
 4         0      1      0
 5         0      1      0
 6         0      1      0
 7         1      0      1
 8         0      0      1
 9         0      0      1
10         0      1      0
11         0      1      0
12         0      1      0
13         1      0      0
14         0      0      0
15         0      0      0
```

## `laag`

```
laag <- function(x, v){
  xx <- rep(0, length(x))
  for(i in v){
    xx <- xx + dplyr::lag(x, i)
  }
  xx[is.na(xx)] <- 0
  xx
}

tibble(treatment) %>%
  mutate(lead_1 = laag(treatment, c(1:3)),
         lead_2 = laag(treatment, c(4:6))) 

   treatment lag_1 lag_2
       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1         0     0     0
 2         0     0     0
 3         1     0     0
 4         0     1     0
 5         0     1     0
 6         0     1     0
 7         0     0     1
 8         1     0     1
 9         0     1     1
10         0     1     0
11         0     1     0
12         0     0     1
13         0     0     1
14         0     0     1
15         0     0     0
```

Comment: When I did a similar "laag" function, I changed the `xx <- xx + lead(x,i)` to `xx <- xx + dplyr::lag(x,i)`. This does not seem to work.

Comment: @mikeytop I'll take a look into it. What do you want to get by `laag`? Can you give me the desired output like `df_desired`?

Comment: No problem. Here is an example where I would like 3 indicator lags.
```{r}
 treatment <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 lag_1 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
 lag_2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
 df_desired <- tibble( treatment, lag_1, lag_2)
```

Comment: @mikeytop I add the code above. It seems that it works properly.